# C# Unity Debug.DrawLine Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How could I list/store the GameObjects that are hit by a Debug.DrawLine drawn between two Vector 3?

using Debug.DrawLine(p1.transform.position, p2.transform.position, Color.green, 2, false);

I want to log the Object(s) hit by the line between p1 and p2.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is not possible with the Debug.DrawLine but is possible with a Physics.RaycastAll:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html

You could do something like this:

You could use a list or an array, if you use a list be sure to include:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then to get your array/list:

```
    RaycastHit[] hits;
    hits = Physics.RaycastAll( transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0F );
    List<GameObject> gameObjectsHit = new List<GameObject>(hits.Length);
    //or GameObject[] gameObjects= new GameObject[hits.Length];
    for( int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++ ) {
      RaycastHit hit = hits[i];
      gameObjectsHit.Add( hits[i].transform.gameObject );
      //or gameObjects[i] = hits[i].transform.gameObject;
    }

    //you now have a list or array of hit gameobjects
```

In answer to your second question in the comments on how to cast a ray between two objects you can do the following assuming you have a objA and objB:

-1. get the distance between the objects:

```
float dist = Vector3.Distance( objA.transform.position, objB.transform.position );
```

-2. cast a ray from objA to objB using the distance as the maxRange:

```
 hits = Physics.RaycastAll( objA.transform.position,
 (objB.transform.position - objA.transform.position).normalized, dist );
```

The rest of the code can remain the same.

Comment: why use a list over an array?

Comment: Good point, an array would work well too, I like sorting, dynamic sizing, and add/remove capabilities of Lists, but an array could be more efficient here, and serve the purpose. I'll update my answer to include an array option.

Comment: If you are using a list, initialize its capacity with the value of `hits.Length`, to prevent unnecessary resizes.

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason I tried to use Debug.Drawlines is it was easy to draw between two game objects. I felt like Raycast could only be projected when given directions. What direction should I give to cast a ray between two objects (p1 and p2)?

Comment: @user3086555 , I updated my answer to include how to cast a ray between two objects, hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Debug.DrawLine is a graphical Debug mode line draw element.  If you want to see what colliders / triggers you hit then you should be looking at the Raycast instead.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html  is the manual page for it.

Essentially you can cast a 'ray' along a direction for a maximum distance and generate an array of colliders that it hits.  There are various different forms, so you'll need to choose the one that best suits for your case.

HTH